# Error cannot find the specified path while executing protractor

Tags: node.js, tfs, jasmine, continuous-integration, protractor

Hi I have write a nodejs application that contains some tests written in jasmine.I am trying to get the test results published in TFS using CLI.

I have installed the following packages

"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.1",
 "jasmine-tfs-reporter": "^1.0.0",
 "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
 "ts-node": "^3.2.0"

Following is the protractor.conf

```
/*global jasmine */
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var TfsReporter = require('jasmine-tfs-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/tests/*spec.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs-prebuilt').path,
    'phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args': ['--loglevel=DEBUG']
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: false,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'PartyAndIndustryDataMigration'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TfsReporter());
  }
};
```

When i try and execute protractor from the command prompt i get error
the specified path does not exist PartyAndIndustryDataMigration

Comment: Did you execute through tfs build or locally? If the error occurs locally, the issue seems not related to TFS.

Comment: I am trying to run locally. I am passed that issue now. Having another issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a minor fix. It had to just correct the path

```
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: false,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: '../PartyAndIndustryDataMigration'
    });
  },
```